# How to identify the source in Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a event handler method, which executes in two cases

one is when user submits the form and user clicks on the button

My problem is, I have a line which is executes only if user submits the form

How to know that the source is Form

Here is the example

```
"formSubmit":function(e)
{
     if(e.currentTarget == "form")// I know this is poor
     {
          //do somthing
     }
     else
     {
          // do other thing
     }
}
```

Any help appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be to have two handlers:

```
formSubmit: function() {  // assigned to form event
    // form only code

    // then run the common
    this.formSubmitBtn();
},

formSubmitBtn: function() {  // assigned to button event
    // common code
}
```